# biblatex: per chapter and per section bibliography

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm using `biblatex` for PhD thesis.

I want to have per chapter bibliographies. Moreover I would like to split the bibliography for each `\section`.
Therefore I use `refsection=section` when loading `biblatex` and use `\bibbysection[heading=subbibliography]` to print the references.

The problem is all list of references have the same title (**References**). I would like to use the number of the `\section` (or even better the name).

I have found the way to do that in the manual (section 3.10.3) but can't make it work.
For instance with the following file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true,hyperref=true,%
        refsection=section,%
        firstinits=true,%
        style=alphabetic,%
        indexing=true,%sortcites=true
        url=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
\section*{References from section \ref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
% \usepackage{nameref}
% \defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
% \section*{\nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Yep}

\section{My first method}

See~\cite{Dubois2010}.

\section{My better method}

See~\cite{Dubois2011}.

\printbibheading
\bibbysection[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

And the bib:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Dubois2011,
author = {Dubois, Mathieu},
title = {New stuff},
year  = {2011}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Dubois2010,
author = {Dubois, Mathieu},
title = {Old stuff},
year  = {2010}
}
```

I get:

```
Bibliography
References from section 1
...
References from section 1.1
```

Where I expected:

```
Bibliography
References from section 1.1
...
References from section 1.2
```

Any idea?
    ...

I'm using TeXLive 2010 on Ubuntu 11.04 (biblatex version 1.4c).

Comment: When I compile your example, I get the *expected* output ("References from section 1.1", "References from section 1.2"). I'm using biblatex v1.6.

Comment: Thanks. I'm updating my install (the last TeXLive comes with biblatex 1.6).

Comment: OK. This works now. The conclusion is that it is a bug from biblatex version 1.4. Thanks.